# Firefox developer tools: is there a way to keep them in front?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

firebug is no longer developed and thus we are bound to Developer Tools if using Firefox. But the developer tools window do not stay in front, for example when selecting a dom element. Is there a way to change this behaviour? Looking into the preferences it seems there are no ways, but maybe... Some terminal command or the like... Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

> Some terminal command

try `wmctrl -r "Developer Tools" -b add,above`